# OS Data Hub - Get Grid Reference

Tags: javascript, maps

I am trying to get the grid reference of a specific location using OS Data Hub API.

The location is based on lat / long coordinates. I would like to be able to get the grid reference and this is then placed into an input box.

The code of the map / marker is below:

```
var serviceUrl = 'https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy';

    // Setup the EPSG:27700 (British National Grid) projection.
    var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:27700', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs', {
        resolutions: [ 896.0, 448.0, 224.0, 112.0, 56.0, 28.0, 14.0, 7.0, 3.5, 1.75 ],
        origin: [ -238375.0, 1376256.0 ]
    });

    // Transform coordinates.
    var transformCoords = function(arr) {
        return proj4('EPSG:27700', 'EPSG:4326', arr).reverse();
    };

    // Initialize the map.
    var mapOptions = {
        crs: crs,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 9,
        center: ([ <?php echo $latit ?> , <?php echo $longi ?> ]),
        zoom: 7,
        maxBounds: [
            transformCoords([ -238375.0, 0.0 ]),
            transformCoords([ 900000.0, 1376256.0 ])
        ],
        attributionControl: false
    };
        
    var map = L.map('map-map', mapOptions);
    
    var marker = L.marker([ <?php echo $latit ?> , <?php echo $longi ?> ]).addTo(map);
    
    // Load and display ZXY tile layer on the map.
    var basemap = L.tileLayer(serviceUrl + '/Leisure_27700/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + apiKey).addTo(map);
```